# Should I protect from such unauthenticated MySQL connect attempts?

Tags: mysql, security, networking

When looking the the MySQL process list, I see the following:
[image]

The IP 23.95.34.214:3968 isn't one of my servers.

Does this mean I have some sort of security breach? Is this something I should worry about / handle?

Comment: Not necessarily. If your MySQL server is internet-facing, then you're bound to be scanned by automated tools, it's just the way it is. You might have more success flagging this post for migration to [Security.SE](http://security.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

Unauthenticated user is a user who connected to mysql, but hasn't sent his password yet.

You aren't hacked yet, but additional firewall rules could improve security.,